# Accessibility Focus Issue on Dismiss View Controller is not consistence

Tags: ios, accessibility

I have a Sample App. Where `First_View_Controller` has a `"Center Button"`. After Click `"Center button"`,  `Second_View_Controller` is Appears via Push View Controller.

Now `Second_View_Controller` has Table View with a Cell `"Header View"` and `Cell list [A, B, C, D]`. Now this Screen has a default left bar button "< Back".

Now On Click `TableViewCell` A and B, I am Pushing `"self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc3, animated: true)" View Controller to Third_View_Controller.`

and On Click `TableViewCell` C and D, I am presenting `"self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)"` View Controller to `Fourth_View_Controller`.

Now Whenever I am coming back to `Second_View_Controller` from `Third_View_Controller` and `Fourth_View_Controller`. My Accessibility Focus in not Consistent with Table Cell Header View.

When Coming with popViewController then accessibility focus to Table Cell Header View but when Coming with `dismiss()` then accessibility focus either goes to Table Cell or `Second_View_Controller` "default back button".

Please help me set consistent accessibility focus to Table Cell Header View on dismissing the `Fourth_View_Controller` always. (Actual issue)

Thanks
Amit Tiwari